# Harvard referencing and in-text referencing for Chapters

Tags: citations, citation-style

Say in the reference list you have referenced a book: can you reference a chapter in that book in-text as such: (Doe 2011, Chapter 3)?

I don't necessarily want to go with the option of referencing each chapter in the reference list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inline citations can cite subsets of texts like sections, chapters, or (more commonly) pages (e.g. when sourcing a direct quote).   Different styles might have different rules on abbreviation (e.g. "Chapter" vs. "chapter" vs. "Ch." vs. "ch.")

Answer (score 1):

While advice, shared by @WBT, is valid for regular books, it is **not appropriate** for *edited books*, which contain collections of papers, authored by different sets of authors. You have to cite and reference each chapter individually. The above-mentioned statements are true, at least, for using *APA Style* (see [this page](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/08)), however, you will need to consult with your publication style guide or manual, if your selected style is different from the APA, to make sure you follow their guidelines.

Comment: After noticing your mention of _Harvard Style_ in the title of your question, I just checked to make sure my answer is still relevant. Indeed, the _Harvard Style_, as I expected, has the same guidelines in regard to citing and referencing chapters of edited books, as the _APA Style_ (i.e., see [this page](https://ilrb.cf.ac.uk/citingreferences/tutorial/theexamples3.html)).